# Installing via apt-get install always give "The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header"

Tags: installation, apt, software-center

When I try to install software like Wine 1.3, I alwasys get something like ...

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ natty/main wine1.3 amd64 1.3.19-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1
  The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.3/wine1.3_1.3.19-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa1_amd64.deb  The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.
```

http://pastie.org/1876695

When I try from Software Center, within seconds, I get

[image]

My internet works, tho I'd say its quite intermittent many times, on wireless ... but I am intending to get a USB Ethernet Adapter to go Wired again ...

**UPDATE**

Is this a Wine 1.3 only problem? I managed to install Wine 1.2 tho?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cleaning out the apt package cache with `sudo apt-get clean`, then try the install again.

Sources:

- http://razcx.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/http-server-sent-an-invalid-content-range-header-during-ubuntu-upgrade/
- http://perpetuallybored.com/2011/02/06/cryptic-error-messages-invalid-content-range-header/

May also be related:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/154505